# How to make swagger-ui.html as default context path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I have an application which with default context path as "/" but I want to make default context path as swagger-ui.html.

suppose if my application runs on 8080 , when I put **localhost:8080** , application should re-direct to **localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html**

I had put following in application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/swagger-ui.html
```

but it is not working, could some one help me

Below are swagger dependencies I am using

```
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
```

Comment: I don't think that's configurable. But you can try the workaround mentioned in https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1080#issuecomment-169185653

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect initial path "/" in controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/swagger-ui.html");
}
```

or you can extend 'WebMvcConfigurerAdapter' class in main class and override method 'addViewControllers' like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers (ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/swagger-ui.html"); 
but did not work

Comment: No I didn't have